# handling event exposed on .net via com in vbs

Tags: c#, .net, com

I want to expose some events to com in .net. But something wrong

Here's the C# code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IEventConnectionPoint
{
    void OnRead(string msg);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ITest
{
    void TestEvent();
}


[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("fst.eventtest")]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IEventConnectionPoint))]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITest))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ComEventTest : ITest
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void OnReadHandler(string msg);

    public event OnReadHandler OnRead;

    private int _count;
    public void TestEvent()
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{_count} at .net 1,typeof(onread) is {OnRead?.ToString()}");
        try
        {
            OnRead?.Invoke("hello");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
        MessageBox.Show($"{_count} at .net 2");
    }
}
```

Here's the code in vbs:

```
function com_OnRead(msg)

end function

set com=wscript.createobject("fst.eventtest","com_") '"com_"the same as "com"
'wscript.connectobject com,"com"
com.testEvent
```

When I run the vbs code,there is an error:method or operation is not implemented (in .net).

pleased help me, what goes wrong?

Comment: I tried to remove the `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]` attribute of the `IEventConnectionPoint` interface, then the error is : specified cast is not valid

Comment: vbs is vbscript, it runs on wscript

Comment: The underscore in "com_" is strange and not necessary.  Try again without it.

Comment: Thank u  Hans Passant , "com" is equivalent to "com_", same error

Comment: It is very strange, It works in vb6.

Comment: It is the same as vbscript in javascript in IE,the handler is `function c::onread(msg){console.log(':: ',msg)}`